# glob and bracket characters ('[]')

Tags: python, glob

/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20] directory has "abc.txt", but when I run this Python code

```
import glob
import os.path

path1 = "/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/\[10,20\]"
pathName = os.path.join(path1, "*.txt")
print glob.glob(pathName)
```

It returns an empty list.

- Can't Python's glob handle the bracket letters or others?
- Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The brackets in `glob` are used for character classes (e.g. `[a-z]` will match lowercase letters). You can put each bracket in a character class to force them being matched:

```
path1 = "/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[[]10,20[]]"
```

`[[]` is a character class containing only the character `[`, and `[]]` is a character class containing only the character `]` (the closing bracket can be placed in a character class by putting it in the first position).

Additionally, since brackets aren't escaped in string literals, your code will look for a backslash as well as a bracket.

Comment: @~unutbu: No, `[[10,20]]` will look for one of the characters in `[102,` followed by `]`. I didn't just double the brackets but created a character class: `[[]` is a character class containing only the character `[`.

Comment: An quick regex that executes this change: `ptn = re.sub('([\[\]])','[\\1]',ptn)`

Answer (score 23):

In Python 3.4 you can use [`glob.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html#glob.escape).

Comment: so doing glob.glob(glob.escape(pathName))?! I still get an empty list

Comment: then your `pathName` is just wrong. if it's a relative path, double check your working directory is the one you think it is: [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Comment: seems that escape is not working correct. `glob.escape('[P]ISBN_4\Image\0001')` produces "[[]P]ISBN_4\Image1" for some reason...

Comment: It is correct. If you want to use backslashes you need to escape them or use raw string: `glob.escape(r'[P]ISBN_4\Image\0001')`, which produces `[[]P]ISBN_4\Image\0001`.

Answer (score 7):

`glob` uses `fnmatch` under the hood. You could use it directly:

```
import fnmatch, os

names = os.listdir("/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20]")
print fnmatch.filter(names, '*.txt')
```

Or using (non-public) `glob.glob1()` (it is present at least in Python 2.3+ including Python 3):

```
import glob

print glob.glob1("/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20]", '*.txt')
```

Here's the implementation of [`glob.glob1`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/glob.py?view=markup):

```
def glob1(dirname, pattern):
    if not dirname:
        dirname = os.curdir
    if isinstance(pattern, unicode) and not isinstance(dirname, unicode):
        dirname = unicode(dirname, sys.getfilesystemencoding() or
                                   sys.getdefaultencoding())
    try:
        names = os.listdir(dirname)
    except os.error:
        return []
    if pattern[0] != '.':
        names = filter(lambda x: x[0] != '.', names)
    return fnmatch.filter(names, pattern)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `path.replace('[', '[[]')` to have arbitrary input paths handled by `glob` correctly.