# How can I do the multiple replace in python?

Tags: python, string, replace

As asked and answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595119/python-glob-and-bracket-characters), I need to replace '[' with '[[]', and ']' with '[]]'.

I tried to use s.replace(), but as it's not in place change, I ran as follows to get a wrong anwser.

```
path1 = "/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20]"
path2 = path1.replace('[','[[]')
path3 = path2.replace(']','[]]')
pathName = os.path.join(path3, "*.txt")
print pathName
-->
/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[[[]]10,20[]]/*.txt
```

- How can I do the multiple replace in python?
- Or how can I replace '[' and ']' at the same time?

Comment: Use regex to split on `'[' or ']'`, then replace individual '[' and ']' with what you want, then join back.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=python+regex+split+example&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=python+regex+split&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import re
path2 = re.sub(r'(\[|])', r'[\1]', path)
```

Explanation:

`\[|]` will match a bracket (opening or closing). Placing it in the parentheses will make it capture into a group. Then in the replacement string, `\1` will be substituted with the content of the group.

Comment: I was hoping to see this solution here :-). It is wise to avoid pointlessly splitting and rejoining strings, due to the potentially large number of unnecessary allocations this would cause.

Answer (score 3):

I would use code like

```
path = "/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20]"
replacements = {"[": "[[]", "]": "[]]"}
new_path = "".join(replacements.get(c, c) for c in path)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also this generic python multiple replace recipe: [Single pass multiple replace](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
path2 = re.sub(r'(\[|\])', r'[\1]', path1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, to avoid regex, I would replace the opening bracket with a unique string, then replace the closing bracket and then replace the unique string - maybe a round about way, but to my mind it looks simpler - only a test would say if it is faster.  Also, I'd tend to reuse the same name.

i.e.

```
path1 = "/Users/smcho/Desktop/bracket/[10,20]"
path1 = path1.replace('[','*UNIQUE*')
path1 = path1.replace(']','[]]')
path1 = path1.replace('*UNIQUE*','[[]')

pathName = os.path.join(path1, "*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

X = TE$%ST C@"DE

specialChars = "@#$%&"

for specialChar in specialChars:

```
X = X.replace(specialChar, '')
```

Y = appname1.replace(" ", "")

print(Y)

TESTCODE