# Trying to create a list of files in directory that range from V2 to V10 using glob

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a list of files within a directory that match the version of specific .csv files within the directory. The file names are "NH [V2].csv" and they range from "NH [V2].csv" to "NH [V10].csv".

How can I create a list that only takes the range that goes from 2-10 but excludes all others e.g. "NH [V1].csv"

This is what I have so far, however it's returning an empty list.

```
nhlist = list(glob.glob('NH [V[2-9]].csv'))
```

I'm trying to to then import all those .csv files into a data.frame as one would do in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrestling with the limitations of [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) patterns, you can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and a regular expression to provide the filtered list of file names:

```
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'NH \[V([2-9]|10)\]\.csv')
nhlist = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if pattern.match(filename)]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, and in a way that helps me understand Python a little bit better! I just switched yesterday and I'm trying to rewrite some R stuff into Python just for the sake of it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could I ask you to clarify what the "r", "\" stand for in the re.compile line? I'm assuming that ranges go in square brackets, that the | stands for OR as it does in R?

Comment: The "r" signifies a raw string which disables backslash escape sequences. The "\`" itself indicates a literal match for the following, so `\[` matches the literal `[`. This is required because `[` is used for a range in the regex pattern, but your filenames contain `[` so it needed to be escaped. Yes, `|` means OR, so match either `[2-9]` or `10`.

Comment: Check out this: https://regex101.com/r/UfiaW3/3 . See the explanation tab at the right of page for a breakdown of the regex pattern.

Comment: @ManuelMartinez: if you're happy with this answer please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it.

Comment: I did already, but my reputation is too low for the vote to be recorded - I'm sorry!

Comment: @ManuelMartinez: no worries about upvoting. I'm pretty sure that you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly the names you want to match, maybe you don't need `glob` for this job.

A simple comprehension could do the trick :

```
nhlist = ['NH [V{}].csv'.format(i) for i in range(2,11) ]

>>>['NH [V2].csv', 'NH [V3].csv', 'NH [V4].csv', 'NH [V5].csv', 
    'NH [V6].csv', 'NH [V7].csv', 'NH [V8].csv', 'NH [V9].csv', 'NH [V10].csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
list(glob.glob('NH [[]V[2-9][]].csv'))
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595162/8489834) answer

But still, this won't match V10 as you requested, so you can do something like (assuming that you have multiple V* in nested directories )

```
list(glob.glob('NH [[]V[2-9][]].csv')) + 
list(glob.glob('NH [[]V10[]].csv'))
```

In otherwise if you got only 10 files under current directory - @PRMoureu 's answer would be better suited for that purpose