# Use 2 string replace without the first having effect on the second

Tags: python, string

Because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595162/1422096), it might be necessary to do this:

```
path = r"D:\Temp\abc[def]\            # (i have many others to process)
path = path.replace('[', '[[]').replace(']', '[]]')
# now we can use glob here with path
```

However, the first `replace` gets mixed up with the second `replace`, and the result is not what is expected, i.e. `D:\Temp\abc[[]def[]]\`.

The only solution I found is to use a temporary character `~` to avoid the 2 `replace` to be mixed up with each other:

```
path = path.replace('[', '[[~').replace(']', '[]]').replace('~', ']')
```

**Is there a nice way to use 2 replacements without the first having effect on the second?**

Comment: @Aran-Frey: I already read the question you linked, but here I explicitely mentioned that I already found a solution using a temporary character, and I wait to find another solution without this.

Comment: Use `glob.escape` and get on with your life.

Comment: There are other answers there, not just the one with a temporary character. You just have to scroll a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replace `]`.

[Special characters to replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.escape) are only `'?'`, `'*'` and `'['`, and are handled by `glob.escape`.

```
>>> print(glob.escape(path))
D:\Temp\abc[[]def]\
```

Comment: Thank you. Not available from Python 2.7, do you think there is a from future import... ?