# Command with 'creates' is not idempotent when using filenames with square brackets

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, square-bracket

I have a task that creates multiple files, if they not exists. It works, until a filename is used as item that contains a pair of square brackets. I've tried to escape with backslashes and `{% raw %}` tags, but it does not work.

Test playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Testfile
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: 'touch ~/{{ item }}'
    args:
      creates: "~/{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - 'test1.txt' # works
      - 'tes[t2.txt' # works
      - 'test3].txt' # works
      - 'tes[t4].txt' # DOESNT WORK
```

First run:

```yaml
changed: [localhost] => (item=test1.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=tes[t2.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=test3].txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=tes[t4].txt)
```

Consecutive runs:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=test1.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=tes[t2.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=test3].txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=tes[t4].txt)
```

Folder content:

```
ls ~/tes*
'/home/user/tes[t2.txt'  '/home/user/tes[t4].txt'   /home/user/test1.txt   /home/user/test3].txt
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20 (via WSL2)
- ansible [core 2.12.1]

Is this a bug, or is there any way to escape the characters so that the task is fully idempotent?

Comment: Kindof a "feature."  In 2.0, `glob` was added to the `creates`.

Comment: @Jack you're right I think it's due to the `glob` *feature* of `creates`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410125/4413446)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that [`creates`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) can handle `glob` syntax (highlighted by @Jack). In `glob` syntax `[` has a special meaning and need to be escaped. I did manage to do it only *manually* by escaping the `[` through this Jinja2 filter `{{ item|replace('[', '[[]') }}`. I did not found an equivalent convenient filter equivalent to Python [`glob.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.escape). However it works!

```yaml
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Testfile
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: "touch ~/{{ item }}"
    args:
      creates: "~/{{ item|replace('[', '[[]') }}"
    with_items:
      - 'test1.txt' # works
      - 'tes[t2.txt' # works
      - 'test3].txt' # works
      - 'tes[t4].txt' # DOESNT WORK
```

*Further reading on `glob` escaping -> [glob and bracket characters ('[]')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595119/glob-and-bracket-characters)*.